# How do I check for a newly created user with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check for a newly created user with javaScript and I can not put this together. I am new to javascript. This is what am trying to solve. Log in with a default username and password After default username/password, allows the user to create a new username and password Return to login and be able to log in with a new username and password that can take you to a success page.

```js
// IFFE
(function() {

    // Removing Div!
    document.querySelector("#create").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#output").style.display = "none";


    //Moving on click login into a function
    document.querySelector("#log").addEventListener("click", logIn)
    document.querySelector("#edit").addEventListener("click", editProfile)
    
    
    // Variable placement!
    let user = {name:"admin", password:"12345"};
    let newUser =  " ";


    // event handler
    function logIn(e) {
        let userName = document.querySelector("#uname").value;
        let userPassword = document.querySelector("#pwd").value;
        if (userName == user.name && userPassword == user.password) {
            document.querySelector("#login").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector("#create").style.display = "block";

        } else if (userPassword == newUser) {

            document.querySelector("#login").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector("output").style.display = "block";

        }else {

            document.querySelector("#error").innerHTML= `Error, please try again`;
        }
            
        
            
        

       
    }

    function editProfile(e) {
        let userName = document.querySelector("#nuname").value;
        let userPassword = document.querySelector("#npwd").value;
        
    

        user = createUser(userName, userPassword)
        // console.log(user.name, user.password);

        document.querySelector("#create").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("#login").style.display = "block";

        
        
    }


   



    


})();

// Outside the IFFE
function createUser(un,pw){
    return {name:un,password:pw}
}
```

```html
  <main>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login">
            <div id="error"></div>
            <form action="/" method="GET">
              <div>
                  <label for="name">User Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="uname" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div>
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password"  id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <input type="button" id="log" value="Log In Here">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="create">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label for="name">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="nuname" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password"  id="npwd" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <input type="button" id="edit" value="create profile">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section id="output">
        <p>You have created a new account!</p>
    </section> <!-- html out -->
</main>
```

Comment: I don't understand... Success page? Check user? What? Storing passwords in plain JS is also such a terrible idea.

Comment: Why do you use `<form>` when you're actually not submitting anything anywhere?

Comment: This is a simulation of login and creating an account without any database. javascript only. @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: What does `userPassword == newUser` do?

Comment: `for` attribute should match an ID, not a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your `user` is an **Object** simply update its key values using i.e: `user.name =`
- The `for` attribute value should match a respective `id`. Not the `name`
- PS: Never store passwords in plain sight
- Use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle a desired *hidden* CSS class.

```js
// Utils:

const EL = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);

// App:

const user = {
  name: "admin",
  password: "12345"
};

// event handler
const logIn = () => {
  let name = EL("#uname").value;
  let pwd = EL("#pwd").value;
  if (name !== user.name || pwd !== user.password) {
    EL("#error").textContent = `Error, please try again`;
    return;
  }
  // All OK, login user:
  EL("#login").classList.toggle("is-hidden");
  EL("#create").classList.toggle("is-hidden");
};

const editProfile = () => {
  const name = EL("#nuname").value;
  const pwd = EL("#npwd").value;
  
  if (!name.trim() || !pwd.trim()) {
    EL("#error").textContent = `Invalid username or password`;
    return;
  }
  
  // All OK, update user data:
  user.name = name;
  user.password = pwd;

  EL("#create").classList.add("is-hidden");
  EL("#output").classList.add("is-hidden");
  EL("#login").classList.remove("is-hidden");
  EL("#output").textContent = `User ${user.name} is now updated`
};

// Init:
EL("#create").classList.add("is-hidden");
EL("#output").classList.add("is-hidden");

EL("#log").addEventListener("click", logIn);
EL("#edit").addEventListener("click", editProfile);
```

```css
.is-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="login">
    <div>
      <label for="uname">User Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="uname" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="pwd">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="log" value="Log In Here">
  </div>
  
  <div id="create">
    <div>
      <label for="nuname">New User Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="nuname" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="npwd">New Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="npwd" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="edit" value="create profile">
  </div>
  
  <div id="error"></div>
  
</div>

<section id="output"></section>
```